# How to use expand operator to get all data from api call

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have a service that calls my api:

```
this.service
        .getData(params, currParams.Id)
        .subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            this.handleData(data);
            this.csvExportService.setDataForCsv(data);
          }
```

Main goal is to get all data using the `expand` operator to pass to the `csvExportService.setDataForCsv` (using this example found here)

https://nightwolf.dev/get-all-paginated-data-using-rxjs-expand-operator/#1

I've tried this but it interrupts my original call:

```
this.service
  .getData(params, currParams.Id)
  .pipe(
    tap((data) => {
      this.handleData(data);
    }),
    concatMap((initialData) => {
      const initialObservable = of(initialData);

      return initialObservable.pipe(
        expand((response) => {
          return response.next ? this.service.getData(params,currParams.Id) : EMPTY;
        }),
        reduce((acc, current) => acc.concat(current.results), [])
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe((resultArray) => {
    this.csvExportService.setDataForCsv(resultsArray);
    console.log(resultArray);
```

What is the correct way to structure this call so that only the `csvExportService` gets all the data and the `handleData` just gets the original call?

Comment: What do you mean by “it interrupts my original call”?

Comment: that first snippet of code fills my table component(original call)

Answer (score 0):

Share the data.

```
const data$ = this.service.getData(params, currParams.Id).pipe(
  shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true }), 
);

data$.subscribe(data => this.handleData(data));

data$.pipe(
    concatMap((initialData) => {
      const initialObservable = of(initialData);

      return initialObservable.pipe(
        expand((response) => {
          return response.next ? this.service.getData(params,currParams.Id) : EMPTY;
        }),
        reduce((acc, current) => acc.concat(current.results), [])
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe((resultArray) => {
    this.csvExportService.setDataForCsv(resultsArray);
    console.log(resultArray);
```